# Elasticsearch range filter for multiplication of two numeric fields

Tags: elasticsearch, search, filtering, multiplication, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an index which I need to filter a multiplication of two fields to be within a range.

First, here's the mapping for my "items" index:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "discount": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An item's actual price would be its price multiplied by its discount.

I need to create a query for items with their actual price to be between two numbers: `X <= price * discount <= Y`

I have looked at the documentation for Elasticsearch, but the [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) seems to only take into account the value of a single field, not the multiplicative product of two fields:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "price": { // only price
        "gte": 10, // X
        "lte": 200, // Y
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder if there any solution besides adding another field which would store the multiplied value to be used in the query.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you index the actual price in the document?  This would avoid creating queries with the script and improve performance.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that would be a preferred of storing the data. But now that I'm aware of the performance overhead, I can see that simply adding another field would be less costly than doing multiple calculations. I should have thought about that in retrospect. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 alternatives:

1. Add the field on index time
2. Use a runtime field

*1* is self explaining, and it is the recommended one in most cases because storage is cheaper than compute. If you don't store it you will have to compute it every time.

2. You can use [Runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html) to generate this new field on the mappings, or in the query.

I will show you both ways:

**mappings**

```
PUT test_product
{
  "mappings": {
    "runtime": {
      "discount_price": {
        "type": "double",
        "script": {
          "source": "emit(doc['price'].value * doc['discount'].value )"
        }
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "discount": {
        "type": "double"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ingest a document

```
POST test_product/_doc
{
  "name": "Orange",
  "price": "10.0",
  "discount": "0.5"
}
```

Run a query:

```
GET test_product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "discount_price": {
        "gte": 5,
        "lte": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now without defining the runtime field in the mappings:

```
GET test_product/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "discount_price": {
      "type": "double",
        "script": {
          "source": "emit(doc['price'].value * doc['discount'].value )"
        }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "discount_price": {
        "gte": 5,
        "lte": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```